# How to write plugins for Aptana Studio 3

Tags: eclipse, aptana3

I would like to know how to write a plugin for Aptana Studio 3. To be more precise i would like to know what language should be used and where should i find an SDK or API. Of course I would also like to know how to integrate my plugin with the actual application since there is no plugin manager ( from what i have read ).

If this is not possible I would like to know if there is already a real-time collaborative code editor plugin, because this is what i intend to implement.

Comment: Aptana Studio is basically Eclipse with the Aptana Studio Plugin. So to get started writing plugins for Aptana you'll be better off learning to write plugins for Eclipse and then looking at the source for Aptana (I believe it is open source) and seeing if you can hook into it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found an answer.

To be able to write plugins for Aptana Studio 3 is actually writing plugins for Eclipse just like @Thomas Clayson said.

If you are searching for real-time collaborative plugin for Aptana, than Saros plugin is your tool. You can find the installation guide here: http://www.saros-project.org/installation.

Hope this helps.